# using Ajax for conditional with rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a view with three checkboxes:

```
<div class="tourny-games">

    <h4>Games</h4>

    <div class="checkboxOptions games show-tabs">

      <div class="show-tab">
        <div class="checkbox uncheckBoxed">
          <input id="" name="" onclick="toggleCheckboxImage(this, &#x27;&#x27;);" type="checkbox" value="1" />
        </div>
        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/...iconlol.png.jpg" class="game-logo-label" />
      </div>

      # two more checkboxes here

    </div>

</div>
```

which create tabs:

```
<div class="tabs">
  <% @games.each do |game| %>  
    <a href="#<%= game.striped_name %>" game="<%= game.id %>" game-type="<%= Game::TEAM_GAMES.include?(game.name) ? "team" : "single" %>" class="tab" style="<%= "display:none;" unless @tournament.game_ids.include?(game.id) %>">
      <%= game.name %>
    </a> 
  <% end %>  
</div>
```

via this jquery:

```
$('.show-tabs .show-tab').live('click', function(){
  var tab = $('.tabs .tab:nth-of-type(' + ( $(this).index() + 1 ) + ')');
  ...      
  if ($(this).find('.checkbox').hasClass('checkBoxed')){
    tab.show();
    ...
  } else {
    tab.hide();
  }
});
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14781203/2128691), I have the following code to set `@game_type`

controller:

```
def game_type
  @game_type = params[:game_type]
end
```

jquery:

```
if ($(this).find('.checkbox').hasClass('checkBoxed')){
  tab.show();
  $.get('tournaments/game_type?game_type='+tab.attr("game-type"))
```

I've tested `tab.attr("game-type")` with `alert` so I know it's pulling the variable I want - it returns either `team` or `single` - but I need to do some conditional checking in other rails code further down the page - how can I do that?

for example, this pseudocode demonstrates one of the things I'd need to do:

```
if @game_type == "team"
  "Team Name"
else
  "Player Name"
end
```

I know that the `@game-type` variable is loaded with Rails, and therefore would just be blank - but that's where the AJAX comes in, and that's also where I'm a bit confused.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9407320/2128691) seems pertinent to what I'm asking, but it's different enough that I can't seem to get it working in my own code.

Comment: Did not get . you want to this controller action or in jquery?

Comment: honestly i'm not sure - i want a variable that i can access from the view and i don't much care how i get at it

Comment: Then you should do it in controller

Comment: right but how is it accessible from the controller when the checkbox is checked after the rails forms are loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at what you've written, it seems to me that you're confusing some aspects of your system. I'll briefly explain what I mean, and hopefully a solution:

> 1. I would call MVC "modular" - it works best when each element does its job
> 2. The "Controller" aspect of MVC is there to handle logic from the view
> 3. Therefore, if you need to create a logic-based solution, you'd need to use your controller
> 4. Ajax, in my opinion, acts as a pseudo-view -- it creates requests without reloading the page; and should only send & handle responses from the controller (not perform logic)

---

From what you've said, it seems that you'd be better loading your conditional JS into its own `game-type.js.erb` from your controller; like this:

```
def game_type
  respond_to do |format|
      format.js { @game_type = params[:game_type] }
  end
end


#game_type.js.erb
#handle your conditional JS here
alert(<%=j @game_type %>)
```

You could tie this into your JS like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.show-tabs .show-tab', function(){
  var tab = $('.tabs .tab:nth-of-type(' + ( $(this).index() + 1 ) + ')');
  ...      
  if ($(this).find('.checkbox').hasClass('checkBoxed')){
    tab.show();
    $.get('tournaments/game_type?game_type='+tab.attr("game-type"))
  } else {
    tab.hide();
  }
});
```

That should output the alert box, which means you're getting the variable from the controller. Then it's up to you to do what you want with it!

Comment: thanks for your answer!  I am admittedly confused, so thanks for explaining things so clearly.  I tried out what you suggested and unfortunately it didn't work - no alert, but i'll keep trying.

Comment: No problem that it didn't work - I believe the fundamental idea is ok, it's just a case of getting it all to gel. The first question is - is your $.get() code correct? I.E does it actually call the action we need?

Comment: that question solved :) had to add `get "tournaments/game_type"` to `routes.rb` as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344045/making-an-ajax-call-to-controller-action-in-rails

Comment: Nice, I was going to recommend something like that, but I figured you'd have done that already

Comment: No problem! Hope everything is great for you!